# Как сохранить картинку в файл ресурса?

Tags: c#, изображения

Здравствуйте.
Например есть картинка в интернете:

```
http://mysite.ru/work_codes/15715-83/4198923--377170.jpeg
```

---

Кароче, у меня есть ссылка на картинку, как мне сохранить ее в файл ресурса программы, а затем вставить ее как **BackgrounImage** для **GroupBox**?

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А зачем в ресурсы? Они предназначены только для чтения. Думаю, [это то, что тебе нужно](http://www.csharpcoderr.com/2012/09/web.html).

```
    Image ImageFromURL(string url)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        var resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        var memStream = new MemoryStream();

        while (true)
        {
            var bytesRead = resStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        var img = Image.FromStream(memStream);
        memStream.Close();
        response.Close();
        return img;
    }
```

Comment: Там все как то очень сложно, мне бы просто сохранить уже по имеющемуся адресу картинку в папку images а затем вставить ее как BackgrounImage для GroupBox.

Comment: напишите-за-меня-код? Ты бы хоть открыл исходники, там все предельно очевидно.
Обновил ответ.