# Преобразовать данные в Bitmap c#

Tags: c#

Есть ссылка на картинку, я получаю её данные c помощью http, как мне дальше запихать её в pictureBox?

Answer (score 3):

Вариантов масса.

Самый простой - [`PictureBox.Load(String url)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6ak7was.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Уже отвечал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/182023/c-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0)